# Azure Mobile Services or ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I've built an ASP.NET MVC 4 app with standard database query tasks and user authentication. Now I want to upload it to Windows Azure and build Windows 8 and Windows Phone client applications. Is it better to use Azure Mobile Services or ASP.NET MVC Web API for these tasks? I have used the Simple Membership Provider for user security, so I'm not sure how can I use it with Mobile Services. Any advices?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use anything aside from Live Connect/FB/Google/etc when dealing with ZUMO directly.

I suppose you could create your own web api or other web-based login that uses simple membership to validate user credentials.  The server would subsequently make a login request to the live connect service (for any validated user) and return the authenticationToken along with the user object back to your app.