# ASP.NET MVC 4 SimpleMembership and Mobile Services

Tags: asp.net, oauth, client, simplemembership, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on a bigger project that will consist of a website and client mobile apps for Windows Phone 8 / Windows 8 / possibly iOS and Android later.
On the website the user can login using a local classic account or using an OAuth provider (FB, Twitter, Google, Microsoft Account).
Now I'm developing my mobile apps, but don't really know how to connect them with the existing user database to allow users all these ways of logging in.

The Mobile Services offer a way to authenticate, but it doesn't seem to be able to work with existing SimpleMembership in MVC 4. Also even if I got OAuth providers working, there would still be a problem how to enable "classic login" users to login in the app.

Do you have any ideas about how to procceed? My goal is to create a seamless experience, that would be unified across all devices. And that requires me to unify the user access methods.

Comment: Not really sure, but I proposed a work-around here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497946/azure-mobile-services-or-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api/15540511#15540511

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a authentication serivce on my website, that created an token for my apps, so that they could later call different other services authenticated. This caused me lose the Mobile Services, but I gained the ability to use any authentication service I want, because the apps are independent on that now, just use the website interface to login.